# Spider-like / roots? mold?

Tags: floor, subfloor, mold

[image]

We recently discovered our dishwasher was leaking under our flooring into the subfloor (formerly the floor - oak before the previous owner added pergo). We’re in the process of cleaning it up and see that there are spidering like dark marks on the floor that I’ve never seen before. Does anybody know what it is?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are these embedded in the floor, or raised up (can you feel them if you rub your hand over them)? Another, close-up and detailed picture might help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Cool picture!!  Very nice.  Sorry about the leak of course.

Comment: Thanks for responding. These are not noticeably raised like a root and are easily wiped away with a paper towel when wet. This is oak flooring that is sitting on a cement slab. The water damage occurred as a semi fast drip (every 4 seconds) from a dishwasher directly onto the cement for a presumably w tended period of time.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like fungal growth to me. Specifically, it looks like the “roots” of [honey fungus](https://gardening.which.co.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/213506309-Honey-fungus). I’ve seen this before on a stack of old PT lumber I had sitting outside for a few years.

Comment: You’re right that this looks very similar to the link you’ve shared. I’ve got a mold remediation company coming later today and will report back (there’s mold on the cabinetry)